# OpenGL : How to rotate (roll) the camera?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opengl, opengl-es

The pitch and the heading work perfectly :

```
fun onDrawFrame(pitch: Float, roll: Float, heading: Float) {
    val lookAtX = cos(pitch) * cos(heading)
    val lookAtY = -sin(pitch)
    val lookAtZ = cos(pitch) * sin(heading)

    val upX = 0.0F
    val upY = 1.0F
    val upZ = 0.0F

    Matrix.setLookAtM(cameraPositionMatrix, 0, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, lookAtX.toFloat(), lookAtY.toFloat(), lookAtZ.toFloat(), upX.toFloat(), upY.toFloat(), upZ.toFloat())

    ...
}
```

But how can I rotate (roll) the camera? I guess I need to rotate the UP vector based on the roll angle around the "line of sight", but it's more complex than I thought.

Does anyone know the formula to calculate the cartesian coordinates of a point A(Xa, Ya, Za) after a rotation of an angle δ (in radians) around an axis B(Xb, Yb, Zb)C(Xc, Yc, Zc)?

This question concerns both **setLookAtM** (OpenGL ES) and **gluLookAt** (OpenGL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can easily be achieved with `Rx * Ry * Rz * T` where Rx/y/z are the respective rotation matrices to rotate around the x, y or z axis, respectively, followed by the (negative) camera translation, which in your case is just (0, 0, 0).

You *could* compute it manually by doing the trigonometry by hand and computing the direction and up vectors for lookat by hand, but there's also the route via `rotateM`, effectively achieving the same:

```kotlin
fun onDrawFrame(pitch: Float, roll: Float, heading: Float) {
  Matrix.setIdentityM(cameraPositionMatrix, 0)
  Matrix.rotateM(cameraPositionMatrix, 0, pitch, 1, 0, 0);
  Matrix.rotateM(cameraPositionMatrix, 0, heading, 0, 1, 0);
  Matrix.rotateM(cameraPositionMatrix, 0, roll, 0, 0, 1);
}
```